# Compute min and max of a tuple list in F#

Tags: f#

In F#, given 
`game: (int*int) list`
I'd like to compute minx, maxx, miny, maxy the min and max values for each tuple dimension.

This code works but seems a bit clumsy:

```
let minX (game: (int*int) list) =  game |> List.map (fun (x,y) -> x) |> Seq.min 
let maxX (game: (int*int) list) =  game |> List.map (fun (x,y) -> x) |> Seq.max 
let minY (game: (int*int) list) =  game |> List.map (fun (x,y) -> y) |> Seq.min 
let maxY (game: (int*int) list) =  game |> List.map (fun (x,y) -> y) |> Seq.max
```

Any hint for improvement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
let minX game = List.minBy fst game |> fst
let maxX game = List.maxBy fst game |> fst
let minY game = List.minBy snd game |> snd
let maxY game = List.maxBy snd game |> snd
```

Comment: These functions of course work for any comparable type, not only `int`. Just remove the type specification, and voila!

Comment: thanks pad for the input. Any idea to reduce the iteration count?

Comment: @sthiers : Use a fold if you only want to traverse the list once.

Comment: @sthiers: I second ildjarn's suggestion. However, it will not look beautiful as you like.

Comment: @RamonSnir: I remove type annotation as you suggested.

Answer (score 5):

Like John's, but easier to read:

```
let game = [(1,4);(2,1)]
let minx, miny, maxx, maxy =
    let folder (mx,my,Mx,My) (ax,ay) = min mx ax, min my ay, max Mx ax, max My ay
    ((Int32.MaxValue, Int32.MaxValue, Int32.MinValue, Int32.MinValue), game) ||> List.fold folder
```

Comment: You could simplify this even further by using `List.reduce` instead of `List.fold`; this also has the added benefit of making the code completely generic, since you don't need to supply the starting state values.

Comment: @JackP. How do you do that without traversing the list twice?

Comment: @JackP. List.reduce assumes there are elements in the list, which can be dangerous sometimes.

Comment: @RobertJeppesen My mistake, I read the problem just after waking up -- you do need to use `List.fold` here.

Comment: @RamonSnir True, but `List.fold` returns the input state for an empty list, which is not necessarily correct either. The safest thing to do is to "manually" check for the empty list and handle it in whatever way makes sense for your app; in that case, you might as well use `List.reduce`.

Comment: @JackP. Graphics libraries often make that design flaw. WPF does. I think it is better to have a `Bound` type that is optional. WPF's `Canvas` suffers from this because all bounds must contain the origin...

Answer (score 3):

There are a few small changes you can make to improve what you have:

1. use `Seq.map` instead of `List.map` to avoid creating new lists and therefore keep memory usage constant
2. use the built-in `fst`/`snd` functions instead of lambdas
3. since `game` is the only argument you can use function composition to make your code more concise

You end up with:

```ml
let minX = Seq.map fst >> Seq.min
let maxX = Seq.map fst >> Seq.max
let minY = Seq.map snd >> Seq.min
let maxY = Seq.map snd >> Seq.max
```

Interestingly, I found this to be quite a bit faster than pad's solution: 0.28 vs 1.75 sec for 10M elements.

Comment: Or if it's in a module, which is a very reasonable case (or even, *the* reasonable case).

Comment: If that's the case the fix is trivial. The functions will work even in a module so long as they're called within the same file.

Comment: But that forces the type to be non-generic.

Comment: The OP is dealing with a concrete type; he didn't ask for a generic solution.

Comment: Then add a type annotation of `: _ -> int` and it should work for all cases. It looks strange? That's because functional languages like generic functions. I personally think that for such a short snippet function, a `inline` keyword would do only good (that of course requires adding a parameter).

Comment: Why use `inline`? It's already the fastest of the correct answers here.

Comment: Fastest of the answers here, is not fastest possible. Inlining would save some overhead.

Comment: @Daniel "It's already the fastest of the correct answers here". On my machine yours takes 0.11s with 1M coordinates whereas Robert's takes just 0.022s.

Comment: I was careful to note _correct_. Robert's returns `maxX=Int32.MinValue` for empty list?? Easy to fix, but broken as-is.

Answer (score 2):

The fold version of pad's answer (only 1 list traversal)

```
let minx,miny,maxx,maxy =game |> List.fold (fun (mx,my,Mx,My) (ax,ay) -> 
    let nmx,nMx = if ax<mx then ax,Mx else if ax > Mx then mx,ax else mx,Mx
    let nmy,nMy = if ay<my then ay,My else if ay > My then my,ay else my,My
    nmx,nmy,nMx,nMy) (Int32.MaxValue,Int32.MaxValue,Int32.MinValue,Int32.MinValue)
```