# F#: What to call a combination of map and fold, or of map and reduce?

Tags: f#, mapreduce, terminology, fold

A simple example, inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562978/compute-min-and-max-of-a-tuple-list-in-f):

```
module SimpleExample =
    let fooFold projection folder state source =
        source |> List.map projection |> List.fold folder state
    // val fooFold :
    //   projection:('a -> 'b) ->
    //     folder:('c -> 'b -> 'c) -> state:'c -> source:'a list -> 'c

    let fooReduce projection reducer source =
        source |> List.map projection |> List.reduce reducer
    // val fooReduce :
    //   projection:('a -> 'b) -> reducer:('b -> 'b -> 'b) -> source:'a list -> 'b

    let game = [0, 5; 10, 15]
    let minX, maxX = fooReduce fst min game, fooReduce fst max game
    let minY, maxY = fooReduce snd min game, fooReduce snd max game
```

What would be a natural name for the functions `fooFold` and `fooReduce` in this example? Alas, `mapFold` and `mapReduce` are already taken.

`mapFold` is part of the F# library and does a `fold` operation over the input to return a tuple of `'result list * 'state`, similar to `scan`, but without the initial state and the need to provide the tuple as part of the state yourself. Its [signature](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/local.fsi#L46) is:

> val mapFold : ('State -> 'T -> 'Result * 'State) -> 'State -> 'T list
> -> 'Result list * 'State

Since the projection can easily be integrated into the folder, the `fooFold` function is only included for illustration purposes.

And [`MapReduce`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mapreduce):

> MapReduce is an algorithm for processing huge datasets on certain
> kinds of distributable problems using a large number of nodes

---

Now for a more complex example, where the `fold`/`reduce` is not directly applied to the input, but to the groupings following a selection of the keys.
The example has been borrowed from [a Python library](https://python.hotexamples.com/examples/toolz.itertoolz/-/reduceby/python-reduceby-function-examples.html), where it is called - perhaps misleadingly - `reduceby`.

```
module ComplexExample =
    let fooFold keySelection folder state source =
        source |> Seq.groupBy keySelection 
        |> Seq.map (fun (k, xs) ->
            k, Seq.fold folder state xs) 
    // val fooFold :
    //   keySelection:('a -> 'b) ->
    //     folder:('c -> 'a -> 'c) -> state:'c -> source:seq<'a> -> seq<'b * 'c>
    //     when 'b : equality

    let fooReduce keySelection projection reducer source =
        source |> Seq.groupBy keySelection 
        |> Seq.map (fun (k, xs) ->
            k, xs |> Seq.map projection |> Seq.reduce reducer) 
    // val fooReduce :
    //   keySelection:('a -> 'b) ->
    //     projection:('a -> 'c) ->
    //     reducer:('c -> 'c -> 'c) -> source:seq<'a> -> seq<'b * 'c>
    //     when 'b : equality

    type Project = { name : string; state : string; cost : decimal }
    let projects =
        [ { name = "build roads";  state = "CA"; cost = 1000000M }
          { name = "fight crime";  state = "IL"; cost = 100000M  }
          { name = "help farmers"; state = "IL"; cost = 2000000M }
          { name = "help farmers"; state = "CA"; cost = 200000M  } ]
    fooFold (fun x -> x.state) (fun acc x -> acc + x.cost) 0M projects
    // val it : seq<string * decimal> = seq [("CA", 1200000M); ("IL", 2100000M)]

    fooReduce (fun x -> x.state) (fun x -> x.cost) (+) projects
    // val it : seq<string * decimal> = seq [("CA", 1200000M); ("IL", 2100000M)]
```

What would be the natural name for the functions `fooFold` and `fooReduce` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably call the first two `mapAndFold` and `mapAndReduce` (though I agree that `mapFold` and `mapReduce` would be good names if they were not already taken). Alternatively, I'd go with `mapThenFold` (etc.), which is perhaps more explicit, but it reads a bit cumbersome.

For the more complex ones, `reduceBy` and `foldBy` sound good. The issue is that this would not work if you also wanted a version of those functions that do not do the mapping operation. If you wanted that, you'd probably need `mapAndFoldBy` and `mapAndReduceBy` (as well as just `foldBy` and `reduceBy`). This gets a bit ugly, but I'm afraid that's the best you can do.

More generally, the issue when comparing names with Python is that Python allows overloading whereas F# functions do not. This means that you need to have a unique name for functions that would have multiple overloads. This means that you just need to come up with a consistent naming scheme that will not make the names unbearably long.

(I experienced this when coming up with names for the functions in the Deedle library, which is somewhat inspired by Pandas. You can see for example [the aggregation functions in Deedle](https://fslab.org/Deedle/reference/deedle-seriesmodule.html#section1) for an example - there is a pattern in the naming to deal with the fact that each function needs a unique name.)

Comment: This answers it pretty objectively, although I'm now tending towards the assessment that there's nothing wrong with re-using names from other functionalities, as long as they are nicely tucked away in a module, i.e. `SimpleExample.mapFold`/`SimpleExample.mapReduce` should also be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have a different opinion as Thomas.

First; I think that not having overloads is a good thing, and giving every operation unique names is also
something good. I also would say that giving long names to functions rarely used is even more important
and should not be avoided.

Writing longer names is usally never a problem as we as programers usually use an IDE with auto-completion.
But reading and understanding is different. Knowing what a functions does because of a long descriptive name
is better then a short name.

A long descriptive function name gets more important the less often a function is used. It helps reading and
understanding the code. A short and less descriptive function name that is rarely used causes confusion. The
confusion would just increase if it even would be just an overload of another function name.

Yes; naming things can be hard, that's the reason why its important and shoudn't be avoided.

---

To what you describe. I would have name it `mapFold` and `mapReduce`. As those exactly describe what they do.

There is already a `mapFold` in F#, and in my opinion, the F# devs fucked up either with the naming, arguments or the
output of the function. But anyhow, they just fucked up.

I usually would have expected `mapFold` to do `map` and then `fold`. Actually it does, but it also returns the intermediate
list that is created on the run. Something I would not expect it to return. And i would also expect it to pass two
functions instead of one.

When we get to Thomas suggestion on naming it `mapAndFold` or `mapThenFold`. Then i would expect different behaviour
for those two functions. `mapThenFold` exactly tells what it does. `map` and then `fold` on it. I think the **then** is
not important. That's also why I would name it `mapFold` or `mapReduce`. Writing it this way already suggest a **then**.

But `mapAndFold` or `mapAndReduce` does not tell something about the order of execution. It just says it does two things
or somehow returns this **AND** that.

With that in mind, i would say that the F# library should have named its `mapFold` either `mapAndFold`, changed the return
value to just return the fold (and have two arguments instead of one). But hey, its fucked up now, we cannot change it anymore.

As for `mapReduce`, I think you are a little bit mistaken. The mapReduce algorithm is named that way, because it just does
`map` and then `reduce`. And that's it.

But functional programming with its stateless and more descriptive operations sometimes have additional benefits. Technically
a `map` is less powerful compared to a `for`/`fold` as it just describes how values are changed, without that the order matters
or the position in a list. But because of this limitation, you can run it in parallel, even on a big computer cluster. And that's all
what **mapReduce** Algorithm you cite do.

But that doesn't mean a `mapReduce` must always run its operation on a big cluster or in parallel. In my opinion you could
just name it `mapReduce` and that's fine. Everybody will know what it does and I think nobody expect it to suddenly run on
cluster.

In general I think the `mapFold` that F# provides is silly, here are 4 examples how I think it should have been provided.

```
let double x = x * 2
let add x y  = x + y

mapFold      double add 0 [1..10] // 110
mapAndFold   double add 0 [1..10] // [2;4;6;8;10;12;14;16;18;20] * 110
mapReduce    double add   [1..10] // Some (110)
mapAndReduce double add   [1..10] // Some ([2;4;6;8;10;12;14;16;18;20] * 110)
```

Well `mapFold` doesn't work that way, so you have the following options.

1. Implement `mapReduce` the way you have it. And ignore the in-consistency with `mapFold`.
2. Provide `mapAndReduce` and `mapReduce`.
3. Make your `mapReduce` return the same crap as the default implementation of `mapFold` does and provide `mapThenReduce`.
4. Like (3) but also add `mapThenFold`.

Option 4 has the most compatibility and expectation of what already exists in F#. But that doesn't mean you must do it that way.

In my opinion I would just:

1. implement `mapReduce` returning the result of **map** and then **reduce**.
2. I wouldn't care about a **mapAndReduce** version that returns a list and the result.
3. Provide a `mapThenFold` expecting two function arguments returning the result just of **fold**.

---

As a general notice: Implementing `mapReduce` just by calling `map` and then `reduce` is somewhat pointless. I would
expect it to have a more low-level implementation that does both things by just traversing the data-structure once.
If not, i just can call `map`  and then `reduce` anyway.

So an implementation should look like:

```
let mapReduce mapper reducer xs =
    let rec loop state xs =
        match xs with
        | []    -> state
        | x::xs -> loop (reducer state (mapper x)) xs
    match xs with
    | []    -> ValueNone
    | [x]   -> ValueSome (mapper x)
    | x::xs -> ValueSome (loop (mapper x) xs)

let double x = x * 2
let add x y  = x + y

let some110 = mapReduce double add [1..10]
```

Comment: This is a nice detailed answer :-) Just to clarify, I did not exactly say not having overloads is a bad thing. I was just saying that I struggled a lot when coming up with reasonable naming scheme to use in Deedle, where many functions have quite a lot of variants. I really don't know what I think about overloads now... I think it's nice to have long clear names if you're doing "software engineering". As for data science scripting, I think the Python approach pretty well - maybe in scripting context, I would like overloads...

Comment: @TomasPetricek Thanks, i also worked in Perl a long time, that in someway supports overloading. Well most of the time we used a hash with named arguments and default values, what is somewhat what overloading is often used for. But because of the lack of typical IDE features we often used long descripte names. It's also even easier to remember. When i learned C# i liked overloading as with Perl you had to implement dispatching yourself. But with F# it changed again. Also consider that overloading messes with type-inference. IMHO the disadvantages of overloading are bigger than its benefits

Comment: @TomasPetricek As a good comparision i would say compare C# LINQ with F# Lists module. F# List has the same features, probably even more, and don't use any overload at all.